# Ranger - file manager open_with WebStorm

Tags: unix, terminal, console, webstorm

I was wondering if it was possible to use the `open_with` option in ranger so that the file or directory would open in WebStorm. Right now it is set to open in Vim, but would also like the option to use WebStorm as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can generate WebStorm Command Line executable and set open_with to it. See answer to the question [How to open webstorm from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879172/how-to-open-webstorm-from-terminal/26889671).

Answer (score 1):

What I did is to program my bashrc to change my default $EDITOR when I am in WebStorm. If I call ranger from the WebStorm terminal it open my files in WebStorm but when I am in a regular terminal it open my files in my default $EDITOR (vim).

I have just added these lines in my bashrc/zshrc (I use Ubuntu):

```
# Check if we are in webstorm
if [[ $(env | grep -i storm | wc -l) > 1 ]]; then
    EDITOR=wstorm
else
    EDITOR=vim
fi
```